# shell scripting, setting a variable in awk and taking that out to use with the rest of the script

Tags: shell, awk

```
echo $fbname | awk -F'[__]' '{print $2 $A_name = $2}'
echo $A_name
```

I am trying to extract a name within the fbname variable like for example, 
`newlist_sammy_card.csv` So I am trying to get the name `sammy` which is between the two underscores and assign it to a variable I can use for rest of the script.

The first line prints out `sammy`, which is what I need, but the second line does not.

Can anyone show me where I am not assinging the variable correctly?

Comment: That should print out `sammy  = sammy` actually and where you went wrong is assuming that you can assign to a shell variable from **within** an awk script. You can't.

Comment: you could capture the output of `awk` to a variable with `$()`

Comment: $A_name = $($2)  like this?

Comment: No, awk is not shell. it is a completely separate tool/language. Trying to set a shell variable inside an awk script is like trying to set a shell variable inside a C program. Even if you could figure out a way to do it, you shouldn't as you'd be breaking encapsulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a LOT of ways to do what you're asking for, e.g. here's a couple more in addition to the other ideas you've received so far:

```
$ fbname='newlist_sammy_card.csv'

$ A_name=$(echo "$fbname" | cut -d_ -f2)
$ echo "$A_name"
sammy
```

or:

```
$ IFS=_
$ set -- $fbname
$ A_name="$2"
$ echo "$A_name"
sammy
```

but I wonder if you're approaching your problem completely the wrong way. We can't tell without more info on what you're trying to do though.

Comment: The `cut` example works only with a single char delimiter, But the second example using `set` is interesting!

Comment: The OP only HAS a single char delimiter. Don't read too much into his **non-working** script :-).

Comment: yeah, you are basically right, but he dropped a comment below my answer

Comment: I see that and I think it's saying he just has a single character as the separator, an underscore. He wants to pull `b` out of `a_b_c`.

Comment: Both solutions work well in this case, but, generally, I wouldn't recommend tokenizing strings with `set`: to do it robustly, not only do you have to set and restore `$IFS`, you also have to turn off globbing temporarily (`set -f` / `set +f`) - all in separate commands; `read` is the simpler alternative.

Comment: Agreed. I doubt if either solution is the best approach but until the OP tells us more....

Answer (score 4):

There is a fundamental flaw in your understanding and reasoning. If you invoke `awk` in your script it is spawned as a program in its own individual right. Therefore all the variables that exist in your current shell are not available to `awk` and vice versa. As such you can not 'define' variables in `awk` that are then visible to your shell. What you should do is 'capture' the output of `awk`, by using the notation `$()`, and assign it to a variable. Consider this example:

```
var=$(awk '{print "test"}')
echo $var
```

This will output

```
test
```

Now in your case, we are actually facing an [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You want to extract `sammy` from the string `newlist_sammy_card.csv` and use that as a variable. One possible solution in pure bash is the following:

```
name="newlist_sammy_card.csv"
temp=${name#*_}
var=${temp%%_*}
echo $var
```

This will output

```
sammy
```

Comment: Nicely done; Your pure shell solution is actually POSIX-compliant (doesn't require `bash` specifically), which is appropriate, given that the question is tagged `shell` generically.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [bash](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html):

```sh
str1="newlist_sammy_card.csv"

# replace 'newlist_' from front of the string
str2=${str1#*_}

# replace '_card.csv' from back of the string:
str2=${str2%%_*}

echo "$str2" # Output: sammy
```

Unfortunately it can't be done in a single run in bash. However it should still perform a lot better than launching any kind of external program.

Comment: between the first two underscores, not the first underscore

Comment: Not really. `[__]` is a character class, naming the `_` twice (which makes no sense).. Let's wait what OP  says. Then I can change it.

Comment: :) Ah, ok! Just add a second underscore in the pattern. Have changed that.

Comment: That still won't work: the intent is to extract a token that is delimited by a `_` on either side; the example given was to extract `sammy` from `newlist_sammy_card.csv`.

Answer (score 1):

[Pankrates's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29499950/45375) explains the problem with the OP's approach well and offers a pure shell solution using shell parameter expansion.

Here's **another pure shell solution**, using a **single command** based on the **`read`** builtin:

Using `bash`, with a here-string:

```
IFS=_ read -r _ A_name _ <<<"$fbname"
```

POSIX-compliant equivalent, using a here-doc:

```
IFS=_ read -r _ A_name _ <<EOF
$fbname
EOF
```

If `$fbname` contains `'newlist_sammy_card.csv'`, `$A_name` will contain `'sammy'` afterward.

- `IFS=_` tells `read` to split the input into tokens by `_` instances.

  - Note that by directly prepending `IFS=...` to `read`, the effect of setting `$IFS` is *localized* to the `read` command - no need to restore the original `$IFS` later.
- `read -r _ A_name _ ...` reads input unmodified (`-r` - no interpretation of backslash escape sequences)

  - Note that `_` on either side of `A_name` is the - customary - name of a *dummy* variable that is used for input that is of no interest, but is needed to positionally extract the token of interest.
    It is a *mere coincidence in this case that the name of this dummy variable is the same as the `$IFS` character*.
  - In this case: `$_` receives the 1st field (before the first `_` char. in the input), and is then overwritten with any remaining fields after the 2nd field, where the 2nd field is read into the variable of interest, `$A_name`.